# Table Valued Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I have stored procedure that accepts a table-valued parameter.

Here is code for that:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ConsolidateInspection]
    @TblConsolidation DTProductCodePO READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @CurrentFormNo AS BIGINT = 0

        INSERT INTO [InspectionDB].[dbo].[FormHeader] 
                      (PONumber, POSuffix, [Productcode], [Stratum], [SpecNumber], [Engineer],
                       [ProductManager], [CountryCode], [SupplierCode], [Supplier],
                       [QTY], [EAGTIN], [INGTIN], [OUGTIN], [InspectionType], [InspectorName])
            SELECT 
                @CurrentFormNo = P.FormNo   
            FROM 
                FormHeader P 
            INNER JOIN 
               @TblConsolidation T ON P.PONumber = T.PO 
                                   AND P.POSuffix = T.POSuffix 
                                   AND P.Productcode = T.ProductCode
                                   AND P.CountryCode = T.CountryCode
           ORDER BY 
               PO, P.POSuffix, P.Productcode


        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END
```

I am trying to execute above stored procedure:

```
exec ConsolidateInspection @TblConsolidation dbo.Temp
```

`dbo.Temp` is the name of a table that has same properties

I tried

```
exec ConsolidateInspection @TblConsolidation Select * from Temp
```

It is throwing an error saying

> Must declare the scalar variable "@TblConsolidation"

Any help?

Comment: Declare the variable in the calling code (must be of the correct type!). Select `INTO` the [table-valued] variable. Supply *just* the variable name to the SPROC.

Comment: FWIW: To supply parameters by name, a `=` [is *required* between the name and value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql): `exec MySPROC @a = 'hello', @b = 'world'`. However, see above.

Comment: No Use.. Still Same

Comment: The second comment says *why* you get the error (if using `exec ConsolidateInspection @TblConsolidation = dbo.Temp` it **will be a different error** and ***not*** "Still Same"). The first comment says how to *actually* call the SP in this case. See the link: `value` is restricted. The syntax is [relatively] well-defined, in terms of what is allowed, if not sometimes awkward.

Comment: Voting to close because the "reported errors" and "actual/executed SQL" keep changing. Work on *one* problem at a time. If SSMS / SQL Server says a variable is not defined, *that variable is not defined*. Fix that, then continue. Pay attention to the comments (to avoid unrelated syntax errors) and existing answer, etc.

Answer (score 3):

`dbo.Temp` is not same as DTProductCodePO! DTProductCodePO is a table type which you should define a variable of it then fill it, then us it as a parameter like this:

```
Declare @Tbl DTProductCodePO

Insert into @Tbl(your fields here ...) 
SELECT ...SAME FIELD HERE... from dbo.Temp

exec ConsolidateInspection @Tbl
```

Comment: The SP that I want to execute "ConsolidateInspection" is not getting executed.

Comment: And Anyways I am not using any other table its just to assign values and see hows its working, I created Temp Table. Do I need to create Table? Cant I directly use TV in my "ConsolidateInspection" ?

Comment: My problem is that I can not able to send data to @TblConsolidation

Comment: You have a table type named DTProductCodePO. You cannot create temp temple as a stored procedure parameter. You should create a variable of DTProductCodePO then fill it then use it as a parameter. what's the problem of your code here?

Comment: "ConsolidateInspection" is my SP that I want to execute. To Execute I did  Declare @ Tbl DTProductCodePO


INSERT INTO @Tbl Select * from Temp Select * from Temp

exec ConsolidateInspection @ Tbl But it is not executing ConsolidateInspection

Comment: it is not executing ConsolidateInspection... what's your mean of this? Is there any error? Or is resulted empty? Or other cases?

Comment: No error. No Result. There are multiple queries inside 'ConsolidateInspection', when I run query individually I get output but when I try with @TblConsolidate it does not work, I mean I do not get output

Comment: Please edit and complete your codes. In your sp there's not any select to show result and it just insert one record into FormHeader table

Comment: I just want to Send data from User of Format DTProductCodePO and use it in my ConsolidateInspection without creating another Table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165117/discussion-between-siamak-ferdos-and-pro-n-apps).